# make Node js rest service talk to Java rest api

Tags: node.js, rest, sockets

I want my java REST api make a call to a Node js rest service. I want to pass an object that contain string  messages which can be parsed and used inside the Node Js's methods and the result is returned to my java REST Service. I need demo code please.

Comment: It's not really appropriate to just ask us to write code for you.  Instead, you should ask a specific question.  How do I do x?  And, show what you've tried and where you got stuck.  Your question so far shows no effort or code at all and asks a very general question and asks us to write code for you.  See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  These references are in the [Hep Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Passing objects between languages can be done using JSON.  You will need some data format that both languages can read and write that can contain your type of data.  There are many, but JSON is probably appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Simply NPM install --save express Axios

then in your app.js file add this code:

change http://localhost:port/users to your java API endpoint.

Your request should now work fine and you should see the data.

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const router = express.Router();



console.log("'/test' call");
axios.get("http://localhost:port/users")
.then(data => res.json(data))
.catch(err => res.secn(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any http client api to make such a request, my recommendation is axios, while there are many apis like fetch etc.

Comment: great apology  for not sharing my code. here is my java code. i used rest template to call the node js server get method, this is just a portion of code.                                                         
 Ma<String,String> req_payload = new HashMap();
     req_payload.put("username", "Peter");

         HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(req_payload);
        String url = "http://localhost:3000/";      
       
         RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();       
          String response= restTemplate.getForObject(url,String.class,request);

Comment: when i call the node js server get/post methods from the java, i am passing object , it can be json object, i was not able to parse this object  from the request.